# Basics of Switch in prograaming

Tags: c

I am preparing for my school test. So for that I have visited lots of websites to clear my doubts about C, C++, Java programming languages. While I was reading those questions, I got one MCQ question which is below:

```
switch (printf("Do"))
{
    case 1:
        //code here
    case 2:
        //code here    
}
```

I execute this code and got execution of `case 2` but I'm not getting why it is executed. Can any one help me to understand?

Comment: Because thats what `printf` returns. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: got it thanks..@tkausl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`printf`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) returns the number of characters it has printed if successful. So in your case it returns 2 and therefore the code under `case 2:` is executed.